# Change Wireless adapter driver in Linux

Tags: kernel, wifi, drivers, opensuse

I am using openSUSE Tumbleweed. I've bought a new PCI-E Wireless card, that supports 5G WiFi (Intel 5100 AGN). It doesn't show up in *lspci*  and even if I take old adapter out it still cannot see my new one. I have tried switching it off and on again in BIOS, but nothing helps. The driver must be installed according to firmware folder

```
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-100-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-3.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-1000-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-105-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-135-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2000-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-2030-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3160-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-3945-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-4965-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-1.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5000-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-5150-2.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000-4.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2a-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6000g2b-6.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-4.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-6050-5.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-10.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-12.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-13.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-16.ucode
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-8.ucode                                                           
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265-9.ucode                                                           
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-10.ucode                                                         
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-12.ucode                                                         
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-13.ucode                                                         
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-7265D-16.ucode                                                         
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-13.ucode                                                         
/lib/firmware/iwlwifi-8000C-16.ucode
```

DMESG:

```
rextuz@linux-c84g:~$ dmesg | grep Firmware
[    0.358267] [Firmware Bug]: ACPI: BIOS _OSI(Linux) query ignored
[    0.401370] acpi PNP0A08:00: [Firmware Info]: MMCONFIG for domain 0000 [bus 00-3f] only partially covers this bridge
rextuz@linux-c84g:~$ dmesg | grep firmware
[    5.713117] psmouse serio2: trackpoint: IBM TrackPoint firmware: 0x0e, buttons: 3/3
[    7.639514] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: loaded firmware version 39.31.5.1 build 35138 op_mode iwldvm
[ 5123.606856] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
[12107.630137] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
[12111.314260] usb 2-1.2: device firmware changed
rextuz@linux-c84g:~$ dmesg | grep Wireless
[    7.622057] Intel(R) Wireless WiFi driver for Linux
[    7.659264] iwlwifi 0000:03:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Centrino(R) Wireless-N 1000 BGN, REV=0x6C
```

*lspci* and *lshw*

```
linux-c84g:/home/rextuz # lspci -vnn | grep -i net                           
00:19.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Intel Corporation 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection [8086:1502] (rev 04)
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Intel Corporation Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak] [8086:0084]

linux-c84g:/home/rextuz # lshw -C network
*-network                                                                                  
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: 82579LM Gigabit Network Connection
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 19
   bus info: pci@0000:00:19.0
   logical name: enp0s25
   version: 04
   serial: f0:de:f1:6f:61:8d
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=e1000e driverversion=3.2.6-k firmware=0.13-3 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes port=twisted pair
   resources: irq:29 memory:f2500000-f251ffff memory:f252b000-f252bfff ioport:5080(size=32)
*-network DISABLED
   description: Wireless interface
   product: Centrino Wireless-N 1000 [Condor Peak]
   vendor: Intel Corporation
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   logical name: wlp3s0
   version: 00
   serial: 8c:a9:82:be:c0:9e
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=4.5.0-2-default firmware=39.31.5.1 build 35138 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11bgn
   resources: irq:28 memory:f2400000-f2401fff
*-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   physical id: 2
   logical name: enp0s29u1u2
   serial: c6:bc:a4:94:d0:53
   capabilities: ethernet physical
   configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.209 link=yes multicast=yes
```

How do I make the kernel to use my new adapter instead or together with the old one?

Comment: What is your kernel version?

Comment: What brand of computer?  Some have a BIOS whitelist that will prevent some wifi cards from working.  With my Lenovo I can't boot it if it has a unsupported wifi card in it

Comment: @GAD3R 4.5.0-2-default

Comment: @Jeremy31 I have Lenovo x220 acctually, i've never heard of such a whitelist. In BIOS it is just enable and disable for wireless.

Comment: Normally, this should work out of the box, so we'll need some more info. Can you post the output of `lspci -vnn | grep -i net` and `lshw -C network`?

Comment: @MariusMatutiae added to the post

Comment: You seem to have everything in order.  Find out the name of your device by running `iwconfig`, then try `ip link set dev NAME up`, where NAME is the name you just found.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae there is only wlp3s0 which stands for my stock adapter, there must be wlp3s1 as the second adapter, but it is not there. If i pull my adapter out wlp3s0 disappears.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop has a BIOS whitelist and the Intel 5100 is not on it

I would recommend calling Lenovo and ordering an Intel wifi card with 5 Ghz from them that will work with the X220 as the option to update the BIOS with a version that eliminates the whitelist might render the laptop useless.

I found the maintenance manual for the X220 and the Centrino Wireless-N 1000 must have been the card it was made with and it is on the list in the maintenance manual, so that is why it works

See http://download.lenovo.com/ibmdl/pub/pc/pccbbs/mobiles_pdf/0a60739.pdf on page 114 and 115 it shows the wifi cards that work.  The Intel 6205 and 6300 are both listed but the 6300 may require 3 antennas.  I still recommend ordering from Lenovo as the whitelist might be looking for one variation of the card and one bought from ebay might still not work

Answer (score 1):

You should see if relevant messages is available in logs or `dmesg`

Look for lines like `missing firmware file xxxx/xxxx`

[image]

(Since I do not have a Linux box at hand, it's just an example found online)

Then you'll know which file to download.

Comment: Nothing like this unfortunately. It only detects my stock adapter 
I'll add output to my post